# Display title on top of image inside horizontal scrollview Programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a text view to an imageview inside a horizontal scrollview programatically. However, this does not seem to work.
Sample Image on in RelativeLayout without scrolling:
[image: Screen Capture 1]

Here is a sample image in horizontal scrolling:
[image: capture 2]
Here is my xml layout:

```
        <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/home_horizontal_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/middle_menu_title" >    

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/home_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout> 
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Inside my test code:

```
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.home_linear_layout);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        ImageView myView = new ImageView(this);
        myView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        myView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        myView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        myView.setPadding(0, 2, 2, 0);
        myView.setImageResource(R.drawable.render);
        layout.addView(myView);


        TextView text = new TextView(this);

        text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4000"));
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.setText("Header Title");

        layout.addView(text);
```

I have also tried using Relative Layout inside the horizontal scrollview without any success.
Inside a simple relative layout like below , I am able to display the title and image but not when it is in the horizontal scrollview

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menu_title"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/render" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#4000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Image Title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any advise?

Comment: PLz describe more precisely what you get from those example and what did you expect instead. Do you want the image to be on the top of your test or on the left ?

Comment: OK thanks for the screen shot at least I see what you mean now. your second solution with the RelativeLayout is the good way to go : LinearLayout don't allow overlapping children.  Pleaze show the result you've got with the RelativeLayout in order to find out what's wrong.

Comment: by the way, if your RelativeLayout is inside an horizontal scrollview, its width should be wrap_content. (so if its content is bigger than its parent, the scroll will be enabled)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your layout :

you say to the LinearLayout parent view to take a width according to its children :

using  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

then you say the children to take a width according to the parent :

using `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`

you have to understand that it can't give a predictible result since they both depend to each other.

I think if you set the width to LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT  on the children it will solve the issue :

```
    ImageView myView = new ImageView(this);
    myView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    myView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    myView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    myView.setPadding(0, 2, 2, 0);
    myView.setImageResource(R.drawable.render);
    layout.addView(myView);


    TextView text = new TextView(this);

    text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50));
    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4000"));
    text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    text.setText("Header Title");

    layout.addView(text);
```

EDIT : seen the edit from the question, LinearLayout can't be the good answer because it doesn't allow children overlapping.

Comment: Hi Looked back at the logs and for some reason it wasn't parsing the color. However, I am still not getting the layout I want. What I am looking for is a layout where the title is on top of the image just like in an article for example. Is there a way to do this programatically. Potentially do I need to create my own View?

Comment: Oh you want the text to be on top ? I didn't get it.  you can may use compoud drawables setting a bottom drawable ( the fourth parameter).

Comment: I didn't understand it because on your 2 examples, you add the text after the image and you're putting it below,  in LineareLayout, the order of addView() call set the order of children, you may want to invert them...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add an image to a **TextView** without putting it in a new parent layout by using the compoud drawables :

```
myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.left, 0, 0, 0);
```

Put 0 to remove drawable, 
You can put a drawable on any side (left, top, right, bottom)
see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29),  it may help you.
the size of the drawable has to match your needs since it use (as it says) the drawable intrinsic bounds.

if you don't have any other view in your **LinearLayout** than a image and a text, it's advised to use compound drawables for optimizations.

EDIT : seen the edit in the question : the compound drawable can't be the answer if you need to overlap your image and your text.

Comment: Hi Guian,
Thanks for your continuous attempt to advise. Unfortunately,that approach didn't work either. I am leaning toward maybe extending the Relative Layout and creating a view that combine the 2 and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Guian,
Thanks again for trying. What I did was my second approach, which was first having a Seperate RelativeLayout with the Image and Text as an object. Then I inflated the view and it works perfect now 
Cheers

Comment: Glad to read that,  you should post your solution as a new answer and mark it as accepted. ( to be found by futur viewers )